# Finding a conformal map sending the region left of the line $y=1/x (x>0)$ to the region right of that line

Tags: complex-analysis

In the complex plane, I am looking for an expression of a conformal map sending the region left of the line $y=1/x (x>0)$  to the region right of that line. All I can think of is some kind of reflection(?) through. However, I cannot find an appropriate function. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: This line is not straight, so it is not very clear what you mean with 'a reflection'.

Comment: Oh I see....I will edit the question.